# A Question from Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

For any two disjoint closed subsets $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ of $ \mathbb A ^n$ show that there exists $g \in\mathbb C [x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$ such that $g(Y_1)=0$ and $g(Y_2)=1$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A=\mathbb C [x_1, x_2, ..., x_n]$.
Since by the Nullstellensatz  any maximal ideal of $A$ is of the form $I=\langle x_1-a_1,\cdots,x_n-a_n\rangle $ and $Y_1,Y_2$ are disjoint, we deduce that no maximal ideal contains both $I(Y_1)$ and $I(Y_2)$, so that $I(Y_1)+I(Y_2)=A$.
We may thus apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem and conclude that the canonical morphism $A\to A/I(Y_1) \times A/I(Y_2)$ is surjective.
Thus there exists a polynomial $g\in A$ mapping to $(\overline 0,\overline 1)\in A/I(Y_1) \times A/I(Y_2)$ and such a polynomial $g$ solves your problem.

**Remark**
Did I really have to use the heavy artillery of the Nullstellensatz to solve the problem? Yes!
Indeed the result is false over $\mathbb R$:
Consider  the line $Y_1=V(x-2)\subset \mathbb A^2(\mathbb R)$ and the  the  circle $Y_2=V(x^2+y^2-1)\subset \mathbb A^2(\mathbb R)$.
The varieties $Y_1,Y_2$ are disjoint but  no polynomial $g\in \mathbb R[x,y]$ can vanish on $Y_1$ and be equal to $1$ on $Y_2$. (This is not quite trivial but can be proved by looking at the complexified situation.)

Comment: Note that once we have $I(Y_1)+I(Y_2)=A$, write $1=f_1+f_2$ with $f_i\in I(Y_i)$, then $g:=f_1$ works.

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg: Dear Georges, in your last remark, you are not thinking scheme-theoretically, correct? Because in that case, $Y_1\cap Y_2=\emptyset \iff I(Y_1\cap Y_2)=1$ and $I(Y_1\cap Y_2)=\sqrt{(x-2,x^2+y^2-1)}\neq (1)$.

Comment: Dear @adrido, you are right: the result is true  scheme-theoretically, and is even easier than the classical result over $\mathbb C$, in that it is purely formal and doesn't invoke the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Dear Georges, thank you for the confirmation.